# API design: should user ids be in url when the api is authenticated?

Tags: node.js, api

APIs that require authentication should contain user id in url calls when the data that is being processed is related to the user who is calling the api?

Imagine an API that is being consumed by a web application  (being both in the same stack)
and it uses an authentication method (cookie, basic auth, etc).

Let's say the web manages books that are being own by users.
When the web app calls /users/:id_user/books lists  books belonging to :id_user.

In this scenario when the request is being processed the user id it is known by the application. For example in node.js using Express and Passport the user id is in request.user.id so for example

So I'm wondering if it is a good approach to omit :id_user as a parameter because the code could do something like that:

**route: /users/books (get logged user books)**

```
app.get('/users', auth(), function (req, res) {

var userId: req.user.id; // Get user id from authentication data.
// Find user's books
books.find({ _owner: req.user.id}, function(err, books){return res.send(books)});

}
```

instead of

**route: /users/:id_user/books (get books from logged user using explicit user id)**

```
app.get('/users/:id_user', auth(), function (req, res) {

var userId = req.params.id_user; // get param from the URI

// For security reasons: prevent the user to access other user books
// by providing another user id in the url by comparing logged user credentials to
// user id from URI.

if (req.params.id !== req.user.id) { return res.send(403); // Forbidden }

// Find user's books.
books.find({ _owner: userId}, function(err, books){return res.send(books)});
```

}

**UPDATED:**

As a result of Jonathan P. Diaz answer who suggested to use "me" as parameter I've been trying to perform the change from req.params.id = "me" to req.params.id = req.user.id in one place instead of writting the lines of code in every route.
Also it is not possible to modify req.params in middlewares (it doesn't exist at point) neither in a callback  passed as second parameter of app.get/app.put/etc. When the method is called req.params.id was again "me" it obviously failed when performing database operations.

The solution I've found is this:

On your routes file add a function like this:

```
var callWrapper = function(callback) {

    return function(req, res) {

      if (req.params && req.params.id === "me") {
        req.params.id = req.user.id;
      }
      return callback(req, res);
    }
}
```

Then build the route in this way:

```
app.get('/users/:id/books', securityProtectionApi, callWrapper(user.showUserBooks));

Note: user.showUserBooks is the controller method and securityProtectionApi is a check using passport for sending unauthorized when the user is not authenticated.
```

Comment: Hi @alfonso-pantoja, i have edited my previous answer to help you set the middleware.

Answer (score 2):

Good question.
I think that the solution one is far more clean.
There are situations where you need to specify who is actually calling the service since is a shared method (you can use the same method to access public data of other users for example), it could be for the logged user or for someone else, what we usually do is use the same idea, as you said **"/method/:id/books"** but when the **:id** is equal to "**me**" ("**/users/me/books**") we assume that is the current user and we use the value saved on the request by passport, if not, the **:id** param is what we need to continue with the process.

```
app.get "/users/:id/books", (req, res, next) ->
    if req.params.id and req.params.id == "me"
        req.params.id = req.user.id
```

**Edit:**
You can add it as a middleware using app.use(). Placing this at the top and maybe using a parameter name more specific to make it clear. [Express app.use()](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use)

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
 if (req.params && req.params.userId === "me") {
        req.params.id = req.user.id;
      }
next();
}
```

Comment: I think it is a great solution. Where should I place that code? I'm trying to using it but I get the error "'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "me"...". The code is used in app.get('/users/:id/booksexpenses', securityProtectionApi, expense.showUserBooks). function securityprotectioApi calls your code and then immediately checks if the user is authenticated using `(req.isAuthenticated()) { return next()´. Otherwise it sends an unauthorized error.

Comment: As I see trying to change the value of req.params.id in middlewares doest not work. When it has been changed it becomes again "me" when executing the route callback. It would be nice to modify the value only in one point (middleware) and not on every route.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your level of security, but you got options. Risks include:

- Incrementing the ID to get access to other user data
- Modifying the
  requests to view other user accounts (account ownership)
- Disclosing
  user account numbers and id's to browser and proxy caches (headers
  stored in logs)

Generally you got 
 - authentication (logged in or anonymous) and 
 - authorization (entitlement, am I allowed to view this page.)

Providing these parameters to the url opens you up to then entitlement checks not being done (common mistake).

My take on it is: Dont use it when user context is important. (Profile, Orders, Account lists, etc) Rather use the session token and infer entitlement on the server.